# how to optimize the following mysql query

Tags: mysql

I  have  a trouble in the mysql query . the query is following.

```
SELECT *  
FROM group 
WHERE  (level IN (3,4,5,6) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 3) 
OR     (level IN (4,5,6,7) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 6);
```

how can I  optimize the query  to  which maybe can drop the `OR` word . thanks.

also,  the query  may be  extended like follow .

```
SELECT *  
    FROM group 
    WHERE  (level IN (3,4,5,6) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 3) 
    OR     (level IN (4,5,6,7) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 6)
    OR     ... ;
```

can someone explain about the Train of thought of  The solution， thanks very much.

Comment: your or clause is killing your query... it can be like this......SELECT *  
FROM group 
WHERE  (level IN (3,4,5,6,7) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 6);   or clear your requirement with data to get more info

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal your solution is wrong, level=3 and last_time=5 wouldn't satisfy OP query but would pass your `where` conditions

Comment: @StefanoZanini do you have another solution then please share so it will be good to optimise query and learning  because sharing is caring :-)

Answer (score 1):

The query looks fine as is. Sometimes it is the case that you want one **or** another condition met. It is the optimizer's job to find the best way to execute the query.

You *can* try help the optimizer, but that shouldn't actually be necessary, so do this only if you really have performance issues.

Your query could be written as

```
SELECT *  
FROM group 
WHERE  (level = 3 AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 3) 
OR     (level IN (4,5,6,7) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 6);
```

because of overlapping criteria, but I doubt that would help the optimizer much.

You could also do:

```
SELECT *  
FROM group 
WHERE Level in (3,4,5,6,7) 
AND last_time BETWEEN 0 AND 6
AND 
(
  (level IN (3,4,5,6) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 3) 
OR
  (level IN (4,5,6,7) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 6)
);
```

So you'd list all values in question first (there is no condition that requires a `level` not in 3-7, and there is no condition requiring `last_time` outside 0-6). Only then list the single conditions. This may or may not help the optimizer.

In any way you should have a composite index on `level` + `last_time`. Whether using this index or doing a full table scan is faster depends on the data, but you should offer such index anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Often the quickest solution is the split it to multiple UNIONed queries. Then each smaller query can use indexes efficiently.

```
SELECT *  
FROM group 
WHERE  (level IN (3,4,5,6) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 3) 
UNION
SELECT *  
FROM group 
WHERE  (level IN (4,5,6,7) AND  last_time BETWEEN  0 AND 6);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's check if MySQL is smart enough to optimize the OR:

```
mysql> explain splain select * from seqid in (1,2,3) or id in (4,5,6);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | seq   | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    6 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

"seq" is a table which contains 1M ints.

Well, MySQL optimizes the OR just fine. It uses the index just as you'd expect. There is no need to tweak the query further.

I suggest you check EXPLAIN of your query to verify your MySQL optimizes it properly.